# Probability of 2 marbles taken one after other being red from a bag of 100 marbles exactly one of which is red

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Exactly one marble in a bag of 100 marbles of equal sizes is red. If two marbles are to be removed
one after the other, the probabilities P1 and P2 of the first drawn marble and the second drawn marble
being red respectively are

A)P1=1/100 and P2=1/99

B)P1=1/100 and P2=0

C)P1=1/100 and P2=1/100

D)P1=1/100 and P2=1/98

The answer key says that the correct answer is C. Can someone explain how it is so?

Comment: It must be the first marble was put back into the bag before the second marble was drawn.

Comment: I think the problem is poorly phrased.  Think of it as two unrelated questions. "Find $P_1$, the probability that the first draw is red."  and "Find $P_2$, the probability that the second draw is red (with no mention of the first draw)."  As the red  one can be in any position, both are $\frac 1{100}$.

Comment: The marbles are said to be removed one after the other. So both the draws must be related, right? So, in the second draw, there must only be 99 marbles in the bag?

Comment: @NeethuKrishnan For the second marble, you need to add the probabilities that the first marble is red and the second marble is red and the probabilities that the first marble is not red and the second marble is red.   Try it.

Comment: I did that..and then I'm getting it as 0 in the first case and 1/99 in the second case. So adding those, the probability will be 1/99. Is that how it is to be done?

Comment: (C) is correct whether the draw is with replacement or without replacement.  Clearly $P_1=\frac1{100}$, and an exchangeability argument (a form of symmetry) justifies $P_2=P_1$.  Without replacement, you can alternatively say $P_2=\frac1{100}\times \frac0{99}+\frac{99}{100}\times \frac1{99}$

Answer (score 0):

If the draws are with replacement, then clearly each time you have a $.01$ probability of getting the red marble.

If the draws are without replacement, you can think of doing the experiment by randomly lining up all $100$ marbles. Don't look at the marbles. What is the probability that the first marble is red? Obviously $.01$. Continue not to look. What is the probability that the second marble is red? Also $.01$. In fact the red marble is equally likely ($.01$) to be in any given position.